# Xander.UI.pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

referring to the attache image, i am using Xander.UI for c# win forms app, after adding this library i am getting this exception where it says that XanderUI.dll does not contain any pdb file for debugging. i have tried ways like loading form Microsoft server symbols but did not work. tried creating another project but it throws same exception again.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually this error was because the Xander lib was not in release mode. they have now published stable version of this lib, install new version from github and this error will be no more.